# Kubectl - Password prompt doesn't allow input, acts like enter was pressed right away

Tags: windows, kubernetes, command-line-interface

When using the kubectl cli in a Windows DOS prompt, I get a prompt to enter a username, that works fine but when I press enter after entering a username the prompt for a password appears and then immediately acts like I hit the enter key, no chance to enter the password, looks like this, from the screen print you can see that I am using kubectl version 1.15.

[image]

If I try this using Git Bash, it behaves the same but responds with the error shown below

[image]

Same deal where the password prompt is not waiting for input.

Anyone ever seen this or have any thoughts on how I can provide a username and password to kubectl without storing it a plain test in the config file?

Also, I am using a corporate Kubernates cluster, so no options to move to a more current version or do anything else that would require admin access.

Comment: Hello. Please include exact steps you've taken to get to this point. How the `kubectl` was installed and what's the version of it (with minor releases). Additionally please tell how the `kubeconfig` file was created/configured.

Comment: Kubectl was installed via a corporate installer, not sure how it works. The kubectl client version is listed above 1.15. The K8S cluster is at 1.14, within the major version -1 / +1 restriction. The kubeconfig was created using kubectl config commands. I did not add any users to the config, I will try that and see if it changes the behavior.

Comment: To properly pinpoint the issue you are having, please provide information how is your kubernetes cluster authenticating the users. You can find possible options here: https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/authentication/ . Additionally please include your .kube/config to check if the configuration is valid. Please make sure that all of the passwords are redacted from the file before posting!

Comment: Dawid, thanks for replying and making an effort to help. I finally got a response from the K8S admins and they are helping with this. I have a personal version running on my pc at home and it works fine there, but that is the current version 1.18. Something about SSO not working at work. Anyways, I now have access to K8S dashboard so I can create my pods and services using that. Again, many thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3):

Posting this answer as community wiki with general guidelines for issues similar to this:

**TL;DR**

**The prompt for username and password is most probably caused by misconfigured `.kube/config`.**

As for:

> Anyone ever seen this or have any thoughts on how I can provide a username and password to kubectl without storing it a plain test in the config file?

There are a lot of possibilities for authentication in Kubernetes. All of them have some advantages and disadvantages. Please take a look on below links:

- [Medium.com: Comparing kubernetes authentication methods](https://medium.com/@etienne_24233/comparing-kubernetes-authentication-methods-6f538d834ca7)
- [Kubernetes.io: Authentication](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/authentication/)

---

The prompt for username and password can appear when `.kube/config` file is misconfigured. I included one possible reason below:

Starting with correctly configured `.kube/config` for a `minikube` instance.

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
clusters:
- cluster:
    certificate-authority: PATH_TO_SOMEWHERE/.minikube/ca.crt
    server: https://172.17.0.3:8443
  name: minikube
contexts:
- context:
    cluster: minikube
    user: minikube
  name: minikube
current-context: minikube
kind: Config
preferences: {}
users:
- name: minikube
  user:
    client-certificate: PATH_TO_SOMEWHERE/client.crt
    client-key: PATH_TO_SOMEWHERE/client.key
```

Issuing commands with above `.kube/config` should not prompt for user and password as below:

```sh
$ kubectl get pods
No resources found in default namespace.
```

Editing `.kube/config` and changing:

```yaml
    user: minikube
```

to:

```yaml
    user: not-minikube
```

Will lead to:

```sh
$ kubectl  get pods
Please enter Username: minikube
Please enter Password:
```

Correctly configuring `.kube/config` is heavily dependent on a solution used (like `minikube`, `kubeadm` provisioned cluster, and a managed cluster like `GKE`). Please refer to official documentation of solution used.

Answer (score 0):

I found this post because I had the same problem, and I knew the cause after seeing people's answers. Comment to add.

I fixed the kube config with the command

`aws eks update-kubeconfig --region region-code --name my-cluster`

- [Create a kubeconfig for Amazon EKS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/create-kubeconfig.html)