# How to delete or stop usage of access token in kubeconfig file?

Tags: azure, kubernetes, kubectl, azure-aks, kubeconfig

Kubeconfig file is containing an access token that acts as a bearer token. It also contains an expiry date. Is there a way to delete/stop this access token from being used so that even if the kubeconfig file has the token, it will prompt for a new login?

Below is the kubeconfig file structure used:

```
apiVersion: v1
clusters:
- cluster:
    insecure-skip-tls-verify: <value>
    server: <server_details>
  name: <name>
contexts:
- context:
    cluster: <name>
    user: <user>
  name: <name>
current-context: <context>
kind: Config
preferences: {}
users:
- name: <name>
  user:
    auth-provider:
      config:
        access-token: <token>
        apiserver-id: <id>
        client-id: <id>
        config-mode: ""
        environment: AzurePublicCloud
        expires-in: ""
        expires-on: ""
        refresh-token: <token>
        tenant-id: <id>
      name: azure
```

Comment: Check this thread it nay help you : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61684152/kubectl-password-prompt-doesnt-allow-input-acts-like-enter-was-pressed-right

Answer (score 0):

**You can get the prompt for new login (username and password) by missconfigured the `.kube/config` file**

There are a lot of possibilities for authentication in Kubernetes. All of them have some advantages and disadvantages. Please take a look on below links:

- [Medium.com: Comparing kubernetes authentication methods](https://medium.com/@etienne_24233/comparing-kubernetes-authentication-methods-6f538d834ca7)
- [Kubernetes.io: Authentication](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/authentication/).

The prompt for username and password can appear when `.kube/config` file is misconfigured.Included one of the possible reason is.

You just need to mentioned the wrong username here

users:

- name: 
  user:
  auth-provider:

example

Editing `.kube/config` and changing:

```
user: minikube
```

to:

```
user: not-minikube
```

Will lead to:

```
$ kubectl  get pods
Please enter Username: minikube
Please enter Password:
```

You can also refer this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61684152/kubectl-password-prompt-doesnt-allow-input-acts-like-enter-was-pressed-right) which has discussed regarding the simmilar issue.

Comment: This doesn't really solve the problem. I'd be interested on WHAT actually to do to fix this - not what **not** to do...